# MySQL - Running Total of Last 24 Hours of Column that Resets to Zero at Midnight

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a running total of precipitation over the last 24 hours from a MySQL table that has data in five minute increments and a daily rain accumulation. The catch is that the rain accumulation resets every night at midnight to 0.

Small section of example table:

```
localdate            |  dailyrainin | runtotal
2018-04-23 23:45:00  |  0.14        | 
2018-04-23 23:50:00  |  0.15        |
2018-04-23 23:55:00  |  0.15        |        
2018-04-23 23:45:00  |  0.17        |        
2018-04-24 00:00:00  |  0.00        |        
2018-04-24 00:05:00  |  0.01        |
2018-04-24 00:10:00  |  0.03        |
2018-04-24 00:15:00  |  0.06        |
2018-04-24 00:20:00  |  0.09        |
2018-04-24 00:25:00  |  0.12        |
2018-04-24 00:30:00  |  0.14        |
2018-04-24 00:35:00  |  0.18        |
2018-04-24 00:40:00  |  0.18        |
2018-04-24 00:45:00  |  0.18        |
2018-04-24 00:50:00  |  0.18        |
2018-04-24 00:55:00  |  0.18        |
2018-04-24 00:00:00  |  0.19        |
2018-04-24 00:05:00  |  0.20        |
2018-04-24 00:10:00  |  0.20        |
```

I'd like to full the `runtotal` column with a running total of the last 24 hours of accumulated rain, but I can't figure out how to overcome the daily rain total resetting to 0 at midnight.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be kindly welcomed.

Comment: So you want a cumulative total of the max daily precipitation?

Comment: Not quite. I'd like a cumulative, running total of the last 24 hours of precipitation. This might not be the hardest query if it weren't for the fact that the dailyrainin column resets to 0 every night at midnight.

Comment: It doesn't seem so hard - but See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)